# Occasional IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException when running a mongo query

Tags: spring, ecmascript-6

I have app with admin panel written on es6 which I know only how to start gulp to build the admin. There is mongoDB which has the admin admin user and password set. I have no problem on 2 laptops to enter the adminpanel, but on the third laptop which is also up to date with the branches I get this exception and I cant log into the admin panel.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Query { "$java" : Query: { "email" : "admin" }, Fields: { }, Sort: { } } returned non unique result.
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.oneValue(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:145) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.lambda$getExecution$4(AbstractMongoQuery.java:122) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:98) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:597) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:580) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.findOneByEmail(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.findOneByEmail(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:206) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.findOneByEmail(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.discernmd.app.service.SecurityService.loadUserByUsername(SecurityService.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:106) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
... 53 common frames omitted
```

I have mongo running and a gulp to build the es6 everything is the same but it will not let me log into the admin panel. I also do have error in gulp which I am not sure if I get on the other places I am using the app

```
error  'Config' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Comment: I got the similar exception while I was moving from spring boot1 to spring boot2. The mongoRepository **findSomethingOrderByCreatedOnDesc** which was returning multiple record referenced by an object was working fine in spring boot 1 while in spring boot 2 it throws **IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException**. The solution is to convert the method name to **findFirstSomethingOrderByCreatedOnDesc** and with this no other change would be required. Detailed official document link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/

Comment: @Kusum I am facing the exception but even using limiting queries like findFirstSomething throws the same exception. It started after I upgraded to spring boot 2.4.0. Could you please let me know of any other alternatives please

Comment: Hi @Ann , findFirst something should return just one response, or it will throw IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException as suggested by the latest spring official documents. Can you cross validate your data? link for reference:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException` means there is some query to the database that should return exactly 1 row/object, but in your case the query is returning either 0 or more than 1 rows/objects.

The exception message shows the particular query causing the error:

```
Query { "$java" : Query: { "email" : "admin" }, Fields: { }, Sort: { } }
```

You should find that query in your code, and make sure that, given the parameters you provide, the query returns exactly 1 object.

Answer (score 5):

We have to use findFirst instead of findOne to fix this issue.

I had the same issue when I use the given method

```
Optional<Person> findOneByStateAndZip(String state, String zip);
```

But I don't see any issues when I use the given method.

```
Optional<Person> findFirstByStateAndZip(String state, String zip);
```